# k3s not able to pull from a docker registry on my lan

Tags: k3s

So I have a registry on my lan, from other machines and from the host curl, nslookup, docker pull/run and podman pull/run work as does just curling the v2 manifests address.  From within a container curlying the address https://docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain/v2/my-image/manifests/latest also works works.  So how does k3s/containerd do dns lookups?  My guess is that k3s is using an internet DNS like 8.8.8.8 instead of coredns for the equivalent of docker pulls? I want it to use mine (or even coredns)

Anyways here's the error is see, the domain suffix was changed.

```
Pulling image "docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain/my-image:latest"
  Warning  Failed     27m (x4 over 29m)     kubelet, infrastructure.lan.mydomain  Failed to pull image "docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain/my-image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain/my-image:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain/my-image:latest": failed to do request: Head https://docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain/v2/my-image/manifests/latest: dial tcp: lookup docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain: no such host
```

Again inside a container this is fine (I can curl the url), and it's fine on the host.  It's also fine from other non-k3s machines on my network.  But things like `kubectl run --image docker.infrastructure.lan.mydomain/my-image:latest testing` give the above error

Comment: Greetings. I'm having an issue with podman unable to resolve a host on the lan. Did you find a way?